# Using lists and tuples interchangeably

Tags: python

I am working on a app that uses `lists` and `tuples` interchangeably and I am having a hard time understanding 1) what's the community "Pythonic" way and 2) is it ok to use them interchangeably?

Examples:

```
val = "hello"
tmp = ("world", "hello")
val in tmp

tmp = ["world", "hello"]
val in tmp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `tuples` and `lists` should not be used interchangeably. Two reasons:

1) There's a very practical difference, `lists` are mutable and `tuples` aren't, so there's a whole bunch of methods, like `append` which do not exist on `tuples`.

2) `tuples` and `lists` represent something semantically different.  This [source](http://jtauber.com/blog/2006/04/15/python_tuples_are_not_just_constant_lists/) does a good job laying this out.

Comment: The best example of `2` I have is an ordered pair. If you're trying to describe a point on the 2D plane you'd use a tuple `(3, 4)`. If you used a list `[3, 4]`, it would imply you could add on to that in some meaningful way. What point does `[3, 4, 5]` represent on the 2D plane? What about `[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"Eggs","Foo",lambda x: frobnicate(x)]` ?

Comment: In layman's terms, a list is a set of things, and tuple is ONE THING with more than one attribute.